# como borrar un archivo de un fichero cuando le plico el delete a mysql con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

buen dia tengo una consult
resulta que estoy agregando dos archivos uno de imagen y otro de video
el de videoes el siguiente codigo para eliminarlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Delete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h3>Eliminar usuario</h3>
        <p>Esta seguro que quiere eliminar este registro permanentemente de la base de datos?</p>
        <form action="delete.php" method="post">
            <input class="btn-danger" type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Eliminar" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sw" value="1" />
            <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])): ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </form><br />
        <a class="btn" href="op.php"><< Volver</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
include("configuracion.php");//si el formulario fue enviado


if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];//le asigno una variable 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE id =".$id; //cadena de consulta para el elemento $id
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)){ //si obtengo resultados ejecutando la consulta anterior
        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //asigno ese resultado a un array asociativo $user
            $videos = $usuario['videos']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $fecha = $usuario['fecha']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $estatus = $usuario['estatus']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $com = $usuario['com']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $fecha_comentario = $usuario['fecha_comentario']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $usuario = $usuario['usuario']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
        
        }
    }

}
;
//conexion a bbdd
if(isset($_POST['sw']) == 1){

    //cadena con la consulta de eliminacion segun el id de usuario
    $query = "DELETE FROM video WHERE id =".$_POST['id']; //No olvidar el WHERE en el DELETE!!

    if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){ //si la consulta devuelve un resultado
        header("Location: op.php"); //redirecciono a index.php
    }else{ //si hubo un error
        echo "Ocurrio un error al intentar eliminar el registro"; //mensaje de error
    }
}

//cierro conexion a bbdd
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

lo que necesito es que al momento de que se borra en la BD  de mysql quiero que tambien se borre directamente en la carpeta donde se esta guardando
cosa que aun no hace solo lo borra de mysql y cuando quiero volverlo a subir este me arroja un error y ya no me permit subirlo a la bd pero si esta en la carpeta y esto causa que no pueda mostrr el video o l imagen

odigo con el que sube el video

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

require('system/conexion.php');
$con = new conexion();



//comprueba si ha ocurrido un error
if ($_FILES['video']['error']>0) {
    echo "ha ocurrido un error en la subida";
} else{
    //ahora se verifica si el tipo de archivo es un tipo de imagen permitido
    //y el tamanio del archivoque no exceda los 1000kb
    $permitidos =array("video/MPEG-4","video/AVI","video/MOV","video/mp4");
    $limite_kb = 17100;
    if (in_array($_FILES['video']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['video']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
        //esta es la ruta donde se copiara la imagen
        //se debe crear o tener un directorio con el mismo nombre
        //en el mismo lugar donde se encuentra el archivo subir.php
        $ruta="video/".$_FILES['video']['name'];
        //se comprueba si este archivo existe para no volverlo a copiar
        //este paso se puede obviar no es necesario
        //o se le puede dar otro nombre para q no se sobreescriba el actual
        if (!file_exists($ruta)) {
            //aqui movemos el archivo desde la ruta temporal a la ruta creada
            //se usa la variable $resultado par almacenar el resultado del proceso de mover el archivo
            //almacenara true o false
            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
            if ($resultado) {
                $nombr = $_FILES['video']['name'];
                    if ($con->subir_video($nombr)) {
                    echo'
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Guardado Exitosamente!");
    window.location.href="op.php.php";
    </script>';
                    } else {
                    die("error");
                    }
            } else{
                echo "ocurrio un error al mover el archivo";
            }
        } else{
            echo $_FILES['video']['name'].
            '<script type="text/javascript">
              alert("Este Archivo ya existe!");
              window.location.href="op.php";
              </script>';
            ;
            echo "<br>".$_FILES['video']['size'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "Archivo no permitido, este tipo de archivo es prohibido o excede el tamanio de ".$limite_kb." Kilobytes <br>";
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: Para borrarlo necesitas la ruta del archivo, sin ella no veo manera de poder eliminarlo. Si tienes la ruta tan solo necesitas usar unlink("ruta");

Comment: si tengo la ruta tal cual como la guardo

Comment: Entonces tan solo tienes que usar unlink() con la ruta, tal como dije, y debería funcionar sin más. Ya me dirás qué tal va :)

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código con el que guardas la ruta del video para poder proponerte una solución.

Comment: listo ya esta editada